# How to stop drush displaying a Drupal error message?

Tags: drush, status-messages

This question is a follow-on from this one about [creating managed files](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220242/how-do-i-attach-an-existing-file-to-a-node). If you look at the question in the link, you'll see that I am writing a drush command to detect all the inline-images in a just-migrated Drupal 8 system, and add them into Drupal as managed images attached to the relevant nodes. To cut a long story short, this bit of code takes the existing file name and creates an entry in Drupal:

```
$file = entity_create('file');
$file->setFilename($file_name);
$file->setFileUri('public://images/'.$file_name);
$file->save();
```

This works fine, except that it very irritatingly displays this error message with every file: `Object(Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityAdapter).uri: The file <em class="placeholder">public://images/rint135_graph4_0.articleimage.PNG</em> already exists. Enter a unique file URI.`

Of course the file exists! That is precisely the point! Despite the error message everything seems to work ok, but I would really like to get rid of those error messages. I guess that they are being set by drupal_set_message(), since they include HTML which of course is pointless in drush - but I can't find any way to switch them off.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Hide the messages with `ob_start()` and `ob_end()`.
2. Avoid the messages by moving the target file out of the way, and moving it back again after saving the entity.